# Протокол прикладного уровня на основе TCP

Tags: c, windows, osi

Хочу разобраться, на каких принципах строятся протоколы выше **4** уровня **модели OSI**, но четкой и лаконично выраженной информации найти почему-то не могу.

Для упрощения, решил пока не заморачиваться с **UDP**, интересует использование **TCP** в роли транспорта и только.

Например, в рабочем проекте для организации приема телеметрии с удаленных объектов использовал простую логику: клиент подключается и шлет квант данных определенного формата, возможно - переменного размера. Затем ожидает от сервера подтверждение. Если подтверждение кривое, либо не пришло в заданный **select()-ом** таймаут - клиент разрывает соединение с сервером. Если сервер не получает входящих подключений или корректных данных в заданный **select()-ом** таймаут - сервер разрывает соединение.

Такая вот односторонняя отсылка данных и односторонняя отсылка подтверждений. На таймаутах. Отослал квант данных, подождал подтверждение. Повторил. Хорошо работает, понятно устроено, легко отлавливаются ситуации некорректности данных. За счет простоты сетевой логики легко наложил на это дело шифрование.

Но хотелось бы чего-то большего, однако попытки сконструировать что-то более сложное, двухстороннее, вызывают кипение мозга.

Меня конкретно интересует:

1) Насколько жизнеспособной и актуальной для современных реалий является описанная односторонняя реализация?

2) В каких случаях стоит определять актуальность соединения при помощи таймаутов, а в каких при помощи "пульса" (контрольного обмена)?

Ведь если реализовать регулярный обмен "пульсовыми" пакетами, то я даже не представляю, как всю эту кашу потом разбирать на противоположной стороне...

3) Насколько актуально использование двух TCP каналов для организации одного "логического" соединения?

Один TCP канал для первичных данных, а другой - для вторичных. Например, объект отправляет первичные по первичному каналу и не может вновь отправлять первичные данные, пока не получит подтверждение обработки со вторичного канала. Второй объект аналогично. Таким образом, на мой взгляд, можно сделать очень сложную логику взаимодействия простыми приемами в коде.

Кто-то называет такой способ организации взаимодействия сервер-сервер. Но я, к сожалению, не нашел информацию по этой теме. Вообще не нашел.

4) Актуально ли организовывать протокол по принципу разрыва соединения после каждого кванта взаимодействия?

Например: клиент подключился, отослал код действия и набор параметров, дождался ответа, затем дождался от сервера код действия и набор параметров, отослал ответ, разорвал соединение. Если коды или параметры некорректные или если нарушен таймаут, разрыв соединения.

Да, я понимаю, что "TCP-рукопожатие", обратная связь на уровне **TCP** и обратная связь на уровне приложения накручивают время и трафик, как снежный ком.

НО! Такой простой способ имеет и огромное преимущество: он предельно прост, как следствие - надежен.

Я знаю, что существует множество протоколов, которые относятся к различным уровням **модели OSI**, но мне хотелось бы разобраться не в премудростях того или иного протокола выше 4 уровня, а в принципах и подходах, на основе которых строятся протоколы более высоких ступеней, и как вообще строится логика двухстороннего обмена, если **TCP** выбран в качестве транспорта.

Comment: В результате наверняка будет построен http-aware rest протокол :) изобретение велосипеда оправдано если есть идея более оптимальной реализации, если этого зерна нет, то и не стоит начинать, имхо..

Comment: Такое уже произошло. Два дня сушил мозг над решением одной проблемы. Затем решил выложить код на хаб, чтобы знающие люди посмотрели. Для обзывания репозитория воспользовался переводчиком. Как оказалось, получилось уже название уже существующей сущности, и оно реализовало практически ту же функциональность. И это без шуток.

Comment: :) оберация сознания :)